# Is there a way to run cypress test to test web application deployed on AWS in different environments?

Tags: cypress

I can give the URL in cy.visit to point to deployed application, but I am not clear on the setup, as I don't have CI/CD yet. The goal is to be able to run this test on a button click, not having to checkout workspace and build the application.

I can give the URL in cy.visit to point to deployed application, but I am not clear on the setup, as I don't have CI/CD yet. The goal is to be able to run this test on a button click, not having to checkout workspace and build the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could test your application directly on a staging/preproduction environment on AWS without A CI/CD.

However, I would not recommend using Cypress against a production environment because for E2E testing to be efficient, you will probably create/delete/edit many things, which may not be suited for a prod env.

Finally, it depends on what you try to achieve with your tests. In general, you will use Cypress to ensure your product works as expected after adding a new feature, for example. You always want to test against the latest version of your code.

On the setup, the E2E tests can be packaged in the project and run manually until you have a CI to execute them automatically.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run